# What is the policy about using GreaseMonkey scripts on SO?

Tags: discussion, scripts

I've written a GreaseMonkey script to add a filter on the featured/bounty page that removes all answered questions.

I'm wondering if there is a policy in relation to scripts and what is and is not allowed...

I also noticed this specific question: [Filter Questions [Greasemonkey Script]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/filter-questions-greasemonkey-script) which leads me to believe there's no restriction...

Comment: Your browser, your scripts.

Comment: No policy, and you can publish your script [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script).

Comment: Scripts are **encouraged**, see the [StackApps.com scripts section](http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts); Stack Apps is a Stack Exchange site. There is even a official keyboard shortcuts user script. How much more endorsement do you need?

Comment: Thanks all..I had to no idea about stackapps. It is quite eye opening!

Comment: Note that you can just use a search query to filter out answered questions, so using your script isn't even "an edge".

Comment: @Servy Do tell :)

Comment: @meewoK What's there to tell.  Go to the search page and just look at the options...On top of that, there's even an "unanswered" tab to choose from that you can use instead of the "questions" tab.

Comment: Yes..but can you easily combine with featured/bounties to get the COMBINATION of "unanswered questions with bounties"? :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You express concern that these things might be used "... in order to gain a small edge". That makes it sound as if StackExchange is a game, and these things could be seen as "cheats" in that game. **It's not!** StackExchange is a collection of question and answer sites. People are rewarded for contributing; whatever you want to do that helps you to make a positive contribution is perfectly OK.

Comment: :) One of the main concerns is to also follow the rules/polices. Just wanted to make sure user scripts are perfectly allowed to do stuff like filtering and digging. Thanks.